# Symfony 4 DateTimeType shows datetime option from year 2014, how to change it?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I need symfony form type datetime to show current year in the select input.

->add('dueDate', DateTimeType::class)
shows year 2014 in the selection input.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add years for input:

```
>add('dueDate', DateTimeType::class, array(
                'years' => array(
                    2019,
                    2020,
                    2021
                )
            ))
```

Comment: I would suggest using something like `range(date('Y')-1, date('Y')+1)` instead of the fixed array.